# Firefox javascript error with page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

On Chrome, the script page loads.
On Firefox it does not.

I have an `<a href="javascript:func(data);"> <a>` on rows of a table.  On click, the function insert html.   Developing on Chrome, everything works. I tried it on Firefox, it does not load.

```
function func(data) {
        $("#div").load("../url/some.html")
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error? At what line? Also does it happen on click or on initial load?

Comment: If you're using jQuery then you shouldn't be doing things like `<a href="javascript:func(data);">`. Come to think of it, even without jQuery you shouldn't be doing things like that.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter. the url reads func(data), page has "false" printed on it

Comment: You have an anchor with a row???

Comment: @epascarello, Yes I have table rows with anchors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the onclick event, not the href.

```
<a onclick="func(data);">Test</a>
```

Side note: You will have to add a:hover{cursor:pointer;} to your css if you use this for your links to give the users the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `href="javascript:foo"` does not work. I think it should be like `onclick="javascript:foo"`.